# Pick random sound from array to play on button click on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, audio, random

I want to select a random sound from an array

```
<array name="cat_sounds">
    <item>@raw/cat_1</item>
    <item>@raw/cat_2</item>
    <item>@raw/cat_3</item>
</array>
```

and to play that sound on button click.

```
//Cat button sounds
TypedArray cat_sounds = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.cat_sounds);
int choice = (int) (Math.random() * cat_sounds.length());

Button cat = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.catSounds);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,cat_sounds[choice]);
cat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v){
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

But for some reason, my code makes my application to crash. What's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work

```
//Cat button
        Button cat = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.catSounds);

        cat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                //Select random sound
                String[] cat_sounds = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_sounds);
                String randomString = cat_sounds[new Random().nextInt(cat_sounds.length)];
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(randomString, "raw", getPackageName());

                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

But creating a new media player after each click is causing the sounds to stop working after 20-30 clicks.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this won't help you anymore, but maybe it will help others.

In addition to your own answer, you need to release the `MediaPlayer` after using it. In your code you are creating too many instances of the player, so it stops working after some time.

You could use

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
```

after `mp.start()`